# Swift mail from Symfony Command

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I try to send a Swift mail from the commandline using a Symfony command. Though I get the following exception.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigE
ngine::renderView() in ...
```

A container is added to this class which I got from the command that is made `ContainerAwareCommand`

The code of the function lookslike this:

```
private function sendViaEmail($content) {
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('123@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('123@gmail.com')
            ->setBody(
            $this->container->get('templating')->renderView(
                    'BatchingBundle:Default:email.html.twig', array('content' => $content)
            )
    );
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

**Update**
The line where the exception happens is `$this->container->get('templating')->renderView(`

As you can see in the code the last line would probably fail aswell as it finally gets there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the error message said, there is no `renderView` method in the `TwigEngine`. `renderView()` is a shortcut in the symfony base controller class:

```
namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller

class Controller extends ContainerAware
{
    /**
     * Returns a rendered view.
     *
     * @param string $view       The view name
     * @param array  $parameters An array of parameters to pass to the view
     *
     * @return string The rendered view
     */
    public function renderView($view, array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->container->get('templating')->render($view, $parameters);
    }
}
```

There you can see the correct method to render a view with the `templating` service.

```
$this->container->get('templating')->render(
    'BatchingBundle:Default:email.html.twig', array('content' => $content)
)
```